# Got function instead of method, even using `def`

Tags: scala, function, methods, syntax

Why, even if using `def`, does the following syntax create a function and not a method?

```scala
def hello = (a: Int) => {
    println(a)
}
```

This is of type

```
hello: Int => Unit
```

And one can use `.apply()` on it, as one can do on functions (but can't on methods):

```scala
hello.apply(5)
```

While these other 3 syntaxes (I'm sure there are other 1000 slightly different ways to express the same thing) produce methods:

```scala
// def name (args) : return_type = body
def hello(a:Int): Unit = {
    println(a)
}
// with type inference for return type
def hello(a: Int) = {
    println(a)
}
// without the '='
def hello(a: Int) {
    println(a)
}
```

(Type for the ones above is `hello: (a: Int)Unit`)

---

**Bonus question**: The type of the first `hello` was `hello: Int => Unit`. This seems to be different than what you would get by defining a function: `hello: Int => Unit = <function1>`. Are they really different?

Comment: `def` just mean definition. Its a kind of value that is always evaluated when you ask for it, and can have parameters. Thus, if it is inside another class or object, the compiler transform them on methods. All were methods, just that the one was a method of zero arguments that returned a function. Also the final one, without the `=` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is a method which returns a function of Int => Unit. You will get this `hello: Int => Unit = <function1>` when you call method, hello having scala version 2.12.

Having version above Scala version, you will get type like this `Int => Unit = $$Lambda$1047/1845297077@184fb68d` instead of `hello: Int => Unit = <function1>`

Comment: Oh, ok. So `def method = some_expression` is the syntax for defining a method that returns an expression. In case the expression is a lambda (`(arg: Type) => body`), then we have a method returning a function. Since invoking a method's name calls the method, then what happens when we do `method(arg)` is not "invoking the function method with argument arg", but rather "method returns a function object, which then gets called with argument arg". So, it's more close to `val my_func = method; my_func(arg)`. Is that right?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini yes that is right. The same applies to `def method(arg1) = expr` just that in this case, you can use **arg1** on your expr. Your example is just a no-args method.